# Tried understand the Soundex algorithm in Python

Tags: python, fuzzy, soundex

What does this number parameter in `Soundex` function mean?

**Code:**

```
import fuzzy
soundex = fuzzy.Soundex(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/yougov/fuzzy/blob/master/src/fuzzy.pyx) it looks like it is the output size:

```
cdef class Soundex:
    cdef int size
    cdef char *map

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        ...
        if written == self.size:
            break
```

Soundex, by default, generates 4-character codes but you seem to be able to change that in this implementation.

Comment: What effect does it have on the scoring if we have less or more character in the result?

Comment: Not sure for this specific case. It is a balance between false negatives and positives. I would stick to the standard value.